# Sharedpreferences issue with samsung galaxy S2(4.0.3)

Tags: android

I have developed on Sip based application for making and receiving a call. And chat feature is also included in this application.

My application runs fine in on Samsung Galaxy y and Sony Ericsson's ICS version. but while using the application on Samsung Galaxy S2 the user is not get registered.its gives me wrong password Error on [Asterisk](http://asterisk.org).

So that means its unable get value from sharedpreferences or its doesn't stores the value on the device.

Comment: any code samples or error log you wanna share....

Comment: I am developing an app that I test run on SGS2 and there are no issues with SharedPreferences. Provide more info!

Comment: @Alborz then what could be the reason for application works fine on other devices except this.

Comment: @KKD i am not getting any error

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it is a massive pain but as far as I can tell you can't use SharedPreferences on Samsung Galaxy S1/S2 phones. No explanation :( Massive pain 
[Error creating SharedPreferences - couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603614/error-creating-sharedpreferences-couldnt-create-directory-for-sharedpreferenc)

Don't know how apps that do appear to save get round it - maybe they use a database.

How I have done it:
Creation:

```
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SaveDataName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString(Constants.SaveDataName, xmlString);
editor.commit();
```

Loading:

```
getSharedPreferences(Constants.SaveDataName, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SaveDataName, "");
```

If relevant: this is in a service.

Comment: thanks for your answer but what about @Alborz comment. see second comment !

Comment: Interesting, how are you creating/editing your SharedPrefs, maybe it can be done a specific way?
Creation:
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SaveDataName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    editor.putString(Constants.SaveDataName, xmlString);
    Log.d(Constants.MsgInfo, "Saving: " + xmlString);
    editor.commit();

Loading:
    getSharedPreferences(Constants.SaveDataName, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SaveDataName, "");

If relevant: this is in a service.

Comment: @juned, let me get home and I will share the exact same code I am using for sharedPref that is working well on two diffrent SGS2 devices.

Comment: @juned I forgot about this, sorry. will do tonight!

Answer (score 0):

@juned, now that I look at the code I see nothing special. Anyhow here are some parts of the code that had to do with sharedPref.

setting SharedPref

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putFloat("longitude", (float)location.getLongitude());
    editor.putFloat("latitude", (float)location.getLatitude());
    editor.commit();
```

and fetching

```
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    GeoPoint userLocationPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (sharedPreferences.getFloat("latitude", (float) 0.0) * 1E6),
            (int) (sharedPreferences.getFloat("longitude", (float) 0.0) * 1E6));
```

Comment: thanks i will try with your code and let you inform if it work for me