# Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, samsung-mobile

I am getting the following error only on Samsung device. Went through [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603614/error-creating-sharedpreferences-couldnt-create-directory-for-sharedpreferenc) but it doesn't really provide a solution.

> Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file
>   shared_prefs/log_files.xml

To be specific:

[image]

This is how I have declared `SharedPreferences` in `onCreate`

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: can you be more specific which samsung + os version + original rom?

Comment: @BojanKseneman : Samsung Galaxy S5 - 5.0

Comment: `private static SharedPreferences getPrefs() {
     return SomeApplication.getInstance().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }` this code is working on our S5 5.0, try changing the name "preferences" tough I doubt that's the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a similar post it looks as if this error is specific to Samsung devices; this was confirmed by multiple users -

[Error creating SharedPreferences - couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603614/error-creating-sharedpreferences-couldnt-create-directory-for-sharedpreferenc)

It might be worthwhile to open an issue.

Comment: I agree. Is there a way we can handle this. Atleast the crash in the App. I have try catch in place though.

Comment: Could you post some more of your code so I can get an idea of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Follow the link given below for shared preference API called TinyDB You can use this which handles your problem.

https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo