# Debugging app always crashing in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to debug an app using Android studio and android emulator. The app gets installed successfully, but when the app comes up it crashes with this message:

> Unfortunately test app has stopped

Below is the log I see ADB monitor. Have deleted the android folder multiple times and reinstalled, it but it does not help.

```
07-27 23:43:40.586 1503-2301/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@20129f4e attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@2c17f0c6
07-27 23:43:41.525 1503-1527/system_process I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-27 23:43:45.546 2902-2902/test.com.integratedcoe A/chromium: [FATAL:compositor_impl_android.cc(559)] Timed out waiting for GPU channel.


                                                                   --------- beginning of crash
07-27 23:43:45.546 2902-2902/test.com.integratedcoe A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2902 (m.integratedcoe)
07-27 23:43:45.649 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-27 23:43:45.649 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86_64/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.0.2/LSY66K/4174711:eng/test-keys'
07-27 23:43:45.649 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
07-27 23:43:45.649 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
07-27 23:43:45.649 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: pid: 2902, tid: 2902, name: m.integratedcoe  >>> test.com.integratedcoe <<<
07-27 23:43:45.649 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:compositor_impl_android.cc(559)] Timed out waiting for GPU channel.
                                        '
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00000b56  ecx 00000b56  edx 00000006
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     esi f77a3f08  edi 0000000b
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000002b
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     eip f770fed6  ebp 00000b56  esp fff1b880  flags 00200286
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00073ed6  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
07-27 23:43:45.653 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00021b1b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+155)
07-27 23:43:45.654 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00023394  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+36)
07-27 23:43:45.654 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0001b874  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+84)
07-27 23:43:45.654 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0021f374  /data/app/test.com.integratedcoe-1/lib/x86/libxwalkcore.so
07-27 23:43:45.654 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00001163  /data/app/test.com.integratedcoe-1/lib/x86/libxwalkcore.so
07-27 23:43:45.731 1136-1136/? I/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
07-27 23:43:45.731 1503-1523/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
07-27 23:43:45.747 1503-2182/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
07-27 23:43:45.750 1503-2971/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity test.com.integratedcoe/com.test.app.service.Authentication
07-27 23:43:45.755 1130-2037/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 589824


                                                 [ 07-27 23:43:45.758  1503: 2971 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f7f76458940, tid 2971


                                                 [ 07-27 23:43:45.759  1503: 2971 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
07-27 23:43:45.762 1130-1130/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1130: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-27 23:43:45.769 1503-1550/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '10b20887 test.com.integratedcoe/com.test.app.service.Authentication (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
07-27 23:43:45.769 1503-1550/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '10b20887 test.com.integratedcoe/com.test.app.service.Authentication (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-27 23:43:45.770 1144-1144/? I/Zygote: Process 2902 exited due to signal (6)
07-27 23:43:45.770 1503-1688/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{10b20887 u0 test.com.integratedcoe/com.test.app.service.Authentication}
07-27 23:43:45.770 1503-1688/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '10b20887 test.com.integratedcoe/com.test.app.service.Authentication (server)'
```

Comment: post your code of accessing shard preferences

Comment: I think this post may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29991934/5241603

Comment: does it happen on all the emulators or just one of them?

Comment: it happens on all emulator. Looks like it is having issues when initializng crosswalk